# Why is the best-practices tag not allowed?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

I noticed that the `best-practices` tag didn't exist, so I wanted to create it, but the system wouldn't let me. I understand that most questions marked with that tag would probably be opinion based, but is that the reason? Should we not ask best practices questions on SO? If not, then is there a more appropriate place for that?

Comment: obligatory reference: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)** See also: [Tag block request: \[best-practice\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60118/165773) and [What tags would be considered “meta-tags”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60166/165773) at MSE

Comment: @gnat uh, oh, too many SE sites. Didn't think to search over there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Best-practices" are, more often than not, opinion-based.
As such, they're off-topic for SO.

Comment: I see. Is there any place else on the SE network where we can ask these questions?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I'm only really familiar with SO.

Comment: If not opinion based they tend to be too broad as well....

Comment: @EduardLuca unlikely. ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @gnat very sad. The truth is that those numbers make sense. It's not very often that people ask this kind of questions, so it's probably not worth it to have a SE site up & running for questions asked *now and then*.