# Why was this question put on-hold as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

I have asked this question on Stack Overflow:

[How do I compile and link unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945685/what-are-some-best-practices-for-unit-test-compilation-and-linking)

It has been put on-hold as primarily opinion based. The explanatory text clearly states the following:
"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, *rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*"

I believe that my question specifically asks for specific expertise, and should not be considered opinion-based. Do you think I'm right, or am I just being biased here?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275039/why-is-the-best-practices-tag-not-allowed

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Comment: Hm, so maybe if I remove the wording "best practices" from the question title it will get re-opened?

Comment: Not as it stands (IMO). "How is linked handled?" - there's dozens of different build systems available, and probably thousands of home-made ones in use in different companies/projects. Too broad.

Comment: Yes, there are, but I am specifically asking the question about `make`. So the broadness is not here.

Comment: A lot of the build systems are based on make (i.e. generate makefiles).

Comment: Aha, thanks for pointing this out. I write my own Makefile manually. How would you call this "build system", so I can clarify this in my question?

Comment: @DanNestor Well as you've seen, my initial close vote for this question was _'too broad'_, which is very similar. While there are good reasonings (and of course makefile template techniques to realize testbeds and automatic run of test cases) to implement unit testing the one or the other way, your question still stays quite broad. One could write whole  books about this topic. Stick with tutorials and recommendations about your particular unit testing environment. It's not likely you get a good answer here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You mean if I'm a beginner and I need some advice on how to use make to link my unit tests, I can't get this answer on SO? This can't be! There has to be a better way to ask my question to get this answer.

Comment: @DanNestor: yes there are. Step one is hitting Google to find examples/tutorials. Step 2 is applying them to your problem (with the docs as a companion). If Step 2 doesn't work, you can ask SO for help getting you unstuck.

Comment: @DanNestor Of course you can get more specific about _particular testbeds_, _particular code organization_, _particular samples for your use cases_.

Comment: @Mat My question wasn't closed because it was unresearched. It was closed because it's opinion-based. What are you saying?

Comment: @DanNestor: It was closed because of two things (IMO again): opinion-based list-type question (best practices), and too broad ("how do I build code with make?"). You can fix the first part by removing that. You can fix the second part by asking a more specific question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How does the organization of my code and code samples have anything to do with what I'm asking, namely how to handle linking with make? Can you detail a little?

Comment: @Mat: thanks for the suggestion. I added some clarification to point no. 2, hopefully this new version is a little more specific. What do you think? Still too broad?

Comment: @DanNestor I've been asking you a [bunch of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945685/how-do-i-compile-and-link-unit-tests#comment42435160_26945685), to clarify your post over there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. Although I have to say, some of the questions seem to indicate that you haven't read my original question :(

Comment: I just noticed that this meta question has been being downvoted. Also some people have been voting to re-open my original question (thanks!) I wonder why is this such a polarizing subject?

Answer (score 7):

Most probably because of the title and this phrase:

> Please give me some best practices.

If the OP had chosen a better title and left this out then the question, while not stellar, would probably have been left open.

Comment: Yeah, I see now that the phrase is taboo on SO. I didn't know that.