# This [policy] is harmful

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

From the tag usage guidelines for [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy):

> Best practice and style are at the core of every program; there is always a better way to do something. Policy helps programmers determine how something should be written.

From the tag wiki description for [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy) (emphasis mine):

> Policy **is a more or less ambiguous** way of describing the best way to do something in programming. [...] This can pertain to the way a method returns a value, the way inheritance is structured, and the way to exit a loop, among other things, and **it can vary from language to language.**

The wiki also includes a link to the [Wikipedia page on "Programming paradigms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm), a language-agnostic page whose topic is covered by more specific (but, for the sake of focus, without any assumption on whether or not they're good) tags such as [imperative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imperative), [functional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional), [declarative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declarative), and so on.

Let's take a look at the [four criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) for burnination requests:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   No. The tag description describes it as "more or less ambiguous".
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   To my understanding, questions about "best practice" *might* be on topic, but they're better suited for (and more much less likely to be flagged as opinion-based or too broad) the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   It's too ambiguous to add anything meaningful, and it shows. Many tagged questions don't actually cover "programming paradigms" or "best practices" but cover a range of topics such as:

   - [Mulesoft RAML validation before Custom Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002096/mulesoft-raml-validation-before-custom-policy) (about "Mulesoft policies")
   - [Importing SAP WSDL with VS17 - Custom tool warning: The following Policy Assertions were not imported/was not handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960863/importing-sap-wsdl-with-vs17-custom-tool-warning-the-following-policy-asserti) (about "policy assertions" in Visual Studio)
   - [Allowing a Lambda function to exclusively put objects into an S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776311/allowing-a-lambda-function-to-exclusively-put-objects-into-an-s3-bucket) (about "Amazon Web Services bucket policies")
   - [ErrorAwarePolicy in Cassandra Java Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112343/errorawarepolicy-in-cassandra-java-driver) (about a type of "LoadBalancingPolicy" in Cassandra)
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   The examples above show that it doesn't. And, more pressing...

There are many questions with the [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy) tag might be considered "off-topic" as they talk about using different APIs within the rules of their respective Privacy Policies or Terms of Service (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735242/this-mobile-app-may-violates-instagrams-policies).

Since many of the questions that are currently tagged with [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy) don't actually follow the tag usage guidelines and that the tag doesn't mean the same thing in all contexts, I suggest burnination.

Comment: “This [policy] is harmful”?

Comment: @HermannDöppes Yeah, that's a much better title.

Comment: Another suggestion, "This tag goes against SO [policy]"

Comment: The tag description sounds like a duplicate of [[tag:best-practices]]. [**Oh…**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275039/why-is-the-best-practices-tag-not-allowed)

Comment: A huge lot of the question seem be about amazon and should be retagged to [[tag:amazon-policy]]. Also a good bunch is related to laravel, maybe a specific tag is warranted for those as well.